# Synchronizing Pepper's speech and tablet

Tags: javascript, python, synchronization, pepper

I'm currently working on my Bachelor Semester Project which aims at programming a Pepper robot such that it can interact with people (more precisely, presenting a compagny which is in partnership with us) and allow users to navigate on a website display on its tablet.

I've done both of those functionalities separately and it works, but I wanted to know if I can synchronize them ? If yes, how (Python, JS, framework) ?

For example, if I ask Pepper to tell me about a job offer concerning software engineering, then it can give me some information about it AND display the related webpage at the same time.

I'm quite new in Pepper's development.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; the quick-and-easy way to do that is to use the [Choregraphe boxes, here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/getting_started/creating_applications/using_peppers_tablet.html) - you can easily show images or webpages on the tablet, and react to touch.

For a more complete solution (for example with nice dynamic webpages on the tablet), it's best to use the [Javascript SDK](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/js/index.html), to send info to the robot when buttons are pressed (service calls, or ALMemory keys), or to subscribe to events from the robot.

One common pattern is to have an app consisting of mostly:

- A NAOqi service in Python exposing an API
- A webpage with:

  - A listener on a signal or ALMemory key, expecting to receive a JSON that should describe the wanted state of the page (which page, which list of buttons, custom titles / labels etc etc.)
  - Buttons result in an API call to the NAOqi service.

The important part is that everything must go through the Python, who should be the one keeping track of the state of the application (the Webpage is just a viewer, and doesn't store state).

[Robot-jumpstarter](https://github.com/aldebaran/robot-jumpstarter) contains some pepper app templates, and service-tabletpage is an example of such an architecture (without the subscription part); it could be a good starting point.